# How can I embed or navigate to a page contained in another namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have two projects in one solution. One contains a page (which is basically a complex control) and another project which is an empty XAML application. What I'm wondering is how to either embed the page into the empty XAML project's main page or at least be able to navigate to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried calling `Navigate()` on your app's main `Frame` control?

Comment: Tried that according to a few other posts I've seen but I get an invalid argument error.

`Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyControl.MainPage).FullName);`

Comment: How about `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyControl.MainPage))`?

Comment: That seems to have cleared it up. Thanks!

Comment: Can't do that with a comment, but I copied that to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyControl.MainPage))`?